# Why isn't the action for my newly created UISwitch being called (Objective-c, Xcode 7.0.1)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiswitch

So I have a UIswitch (firstSwitch) which when it is ON calls an action where it creates another UISwitch (secondSwitch). Then I want to repeat this step where the newly created UISwitch (secondSwitch) calls an action where it creates a new UISwitch (thirdSwitch) when it is switched ON. But the problem is, the first newly created switch (secondSwitch) does not detect the ON state so it cannot create the new UISwitch (thirdSwitch). Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Below are snippets of code to get a better idea (please disregard the positioning of x, y, width, height):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadFirstSwitch];

    [firstSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchIsChanged:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    //This secondSwitch does not detect the change in state to ON
    [secondSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchIsChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)loadFirstSwitch {
    firstSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth - 50 - buttonPadding, 527.5 + buttonWidth, 50, 27)];
    [scrollView addSubview:firstSwitch];
}

- (void)loadSecondSwitch{
    secondSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth - 50 - buttonPadding, 527.5 + buttonWidth, 50, 27)];
    [scrollView addSubview:secondSwitch];
}

- (void)loadThirdSwitch{
    thirdSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth - 50 - buttonPadding, 527.5 + buttonWidth, 50, 27)];
    [scrollView addSubview:thirdSwitch];
}

- (void) switchIsChanged:(UISwitch *)paramSender{
    if(paramSender == firstSwitch){
        if([paramSender isOn]){
            [self loadSecondSwitch];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Switch is off");
        }
    }

if(paramSender == secondSwitch){
        if([paramSender isOn]){
            [self loadThirdSwitch];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Switch is off");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding target to secondSwitch before it is created, it should be done after it is created, better to put in the function `loadSecondSwitch`, so you code looks like

```
- (void)loadSecondSwitch{
    secondSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth - 50 - buttonPadding, 527.5 + buttonWidth, 50, 27)];
    [scrollView addSubview:secondSwitch];

   [secondSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchIsChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Remove `[secondSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchIsChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` from `viewDidLoad`.

I hope it works for you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a target and selector to the second switch before it's instantiated. Try moving `[secondSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchIsChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` to inside `loadSecondSwitch`.